# Compute the fundamental group of a five - pointed star ( boundary plus interior )

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, knot-theory

Compute the fundamental group of a five-pointed star ( boundary plus interior ).

Knowing that I have taken only chapter 1 & 2 of " introduction to knot theory " of Richard H. Crowell and Ralph H. Fox.

Which includes the fundamental group of the circle but does not include van Kampen theorem.

Could anyone give me a hint for the solution, please?

Comment: Perhaps a picture would help.  Isn't the region you describe contractible?

Comment: If you choose the center of your five-pointed star as base point for your fundamental group, you can shrink any closed path to the constant path by scaling. This is because the star is star-shaped around the center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say that $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^n$ is *star-shaped* if there is $p \in \Omega$ with the following property : for all $ q \in \Omega$, the segment $[p,q] \subset \Omega$.

We know that

> If $\Omega$ is star-shaped, then $\Omega$ is contractible, that is homotopy equivalent to a point. In particular, $\Omega$ is connected and simply-connected.

For proof of this statement see Lemma 2.11 and Theorem 3.4 [here](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/Courses/MA3427/MA3427_Mich2018_CourseNotes/MA3427_Mich2018_PartII.pdf)

Now we have that:

> A topological space X is simply connected if and only if X is path-connected and the fundamental group of X at each point is trivial.

Por proof of this see Theorem 2.3 [here](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/Courses/421/421S2_0809.pdf)

Therefore for a star shaped region, the fundamental group is trivial.

As you asked for a hint I would try prove these claims without clicking the links first.